# using STRUCT in bigquery

Tags: struct, google-bigquery

i have some problem in BigQuery,

i have 2 tables
first tables is paymentdate

| Customer_id | paid_date |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 2021/01/23 |
| aaa | 2021/01/24 |
| bbb | 2020/01/12 |

second table is amount_table

| Costemer_id | date | conceptID | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2021/01/23 | principal | 1000 |
| aaa | 2021/01/23 | interest | 200 |
| aaa | 2021/01/24 | late_fee | 30 |
| aaa | 2021/01/24 | principal | 1000 |
| bbb | 2020/01/12 | principal | 250 |

and i want to write query using STRUCT and the result that i want is :

| customer_id | paid_date | concept_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2021/01/23 | principal | 100000 |
|  |  | interest | 200 |
| aaa | 2021/01/24 | late_fee | 30 |
|  |  | principal | 10000 |
| bbb | 2020/01/12 | principal | 250 |

i already write query but it doesnt work

> select `paymentdate`.customer_id, `paymentdate`.paid_date , array(select struct(concept_id,amount) from `amount_table` where `amount_table`.customer_id=`paymentdate`.customer_id and `amount_table`.paid_date=`paymentdate`.paid_date) from `paymentdate`

anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `paid_date` with `date` in your query:  `and amount_table.date=paymentdate.paid_date`.

Also consider [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg):

```
select 
  paymentdate.customer_id,
  paymentdate.paid_date,
  array_agg(struct(concept_id,amount))
from paymentdate join amount_table 
  on paymentdate.customer_id = amount_table.customer_id
  and paymentdate.paid_date = amount_table.date
group by 1, 2
```